# How to pull a single image from any docker repository?

Tags: docker, lxc

The docker repositories contains multiple images. Is it possible to just pull the specific image from Repository.

When I use:

```
docker pull  ubuntu
```

It pulls down around 8-10 different versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If there's a specific image that's tagged, you could use the --tag= (or -t) operator to pull the specific image you're looking for.  There's a shorthand form for the command as well, which uses just a colon between the image name and the tag.

So if you want the version of ubuntu that's tagged as quantal, you could use:

```
docker pull ubuntu:quantal
```

The longer forms would be:

```
docker pull --tag="quantal" ubuntu
docker pull --t quantal ubuntu
```

This will still pull the historical layers used to build the final image, but will be a smaller subset than all of the layers for ubuntu.

[Updated to include Ben's note on shorthand from below. Thanks!]

Comment: As short hand you can also use a colon. `docker pull ubuntu:quantal`

Comment: Cool, Thanks Johncosta and Ben

Comment: any idea how to list available tag names in docker search?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
docker pull reponame:tagname
docker pull ubantu:quantal
```