# view tags of a docker image from index.docker.io?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

How does one view what tags are available for a docker image on index.docker.io before pulling? Using sudo docker pull debian will get me all the tags associated with debian which I don't need.

Comment: I think that it is not possible at this moment. Idea behind this is that tags for an image should share majority of the content of the whole image - and in case you want to download just one tag, you probably end up downloading major part of the image anyway.

Comment: I don't see any good argument for that 'idea'. My view on this is that different tags for an image should be functionally alike for the user, such as version number of the same software. However, that does not imply that most file system layers of those images are the same. E.g., the first statement could be an `apt-get upgrade` in which case a newer build could be different from the second file layer up. My advise would be to create an issue for this on the Github Docker page.

Answer (score 9):

As of today [the Docker registry](http://blog.docker.io/2014/03/introducing-private-repos-webhooks-and-more/) exposes this in the index. See, for example, the [Ubuntu base image tags](https://index.docker.io/_/ubuntu/tags) which shows each tag and the filesystem contents of each layer. Via the API:

```
$ curl https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags
[{"layer": "9cd978db300e27386baa9dd791bf6dc818f13e52235b26e95703361ec3c94dc6", "name": "latest"}, {"layer": "9cc9ea5ea540116b89e41898dd30858107c1175260fb7ff50322b34704092232", "name": "10.04"}, ...
```

Comment: does this imply that the other functionality in https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3411 is also already implemented and that that issue can be closed?

Comment: Pushing tags is still not supported. Trying to push a tag will result in the error `Invalid repository name (myrepo:mytag), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed`.

Comment: A workaround for that is to untag `myrepo:*` and keep only `myrepo:wantedtag` locally; then `docker push myrepo`. But indeed, the issue still exists.

Answer (score -7):

Found what I wanted with this [How to pull a single image from any docker repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428237/how-to-pull-a-single-image-from-any-docker-repository)

`docker pull <image_name>:<tag>`

Example: `docker pull debian:stable`

Comment: That's not really answers your own question which was: how to list the available tags of a repository :)